# WordPress Menu Hover Background Color Height

Tags: html, css, wordpress

Hi This is my website http://elisse.com.au/

I am trying to change the color on hover of top menu which is fine but I want it cover the full height. Currently it is only displaying on text background

Comment: Stack Overflow really doesn't work like this - you're supposed to add the relevant code into the question itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add css property in `wp-content/themes/lyrical/style.css`

```
.main-navigation a{
padding: 48px 10px;
line-height: 44px;
margin-left:0px; //set margin-left:0px
margin-right:0px //set margin-right:0px
}
```

Comment: Worked Flawlessly :)

Answer (score 0):

Create another div covering the whole text area and give height and width in order to maintain the balance. :D also I will give you another suggestion to help your tabs, create a fade animation in CSS.
Add the following statement in your original CSS div make sure you have the hover keyword:

transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;

Cheers